# 12.04 LTS 2 without screensaver?

Tags: 12.04, installation, xorg

I don't know if this has to do with xorg-xserver-bug currently ? ( at a friend's notebook )

screensaver resp. xscreensaver are installed but it does not appear in the system-settings as tool - for to be adjusted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-screensaver

sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra
```

Create an autostart file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/xdg/autostart/screensaver.desktop
```

Copy and paste the following into it:

```
[Desktop Entry]Name=ScreensaverType=ApplicatonExec=xscreensaver -nosplash
```

Now reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: thx. Now my friend will be happy.